# Printed text in while loop doesn't act as expected

Tags: php

This code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $username=$row["username"];
    $currentroles[$username]=$row["role"];

    print "abc";

    echo "<tr><td>$username</td>";

    echo "def";

    echo "<td><select name=\"role[$username]\">";

    if($row["role"]=='admin')
    {
        echo "<option value=\"admin\">admin</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"user\">user</option>";
    }
    else if($row["role"]=='user')
    {
        echo "<option value=\"user\">user</option>";
        echo "<option value=\"admin\">admin</option>";
    }

   echo "</select></td></tr><br/>";
}
```

Produces this page:

[image: page produced by the code]

(this is just a part of the page, there are as many users with a dropdown list as "abcdef"s)

I have no idea why are the "abc", "def" strings at the top of the page. If I take them out, there are empty lines in the page (instead of "abcdef)", even though I never printed `<br>`. What's going on?

Comment: can you please write what $result return?

Comment: try replacing `echo "<tr><td>".$username."</td>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because they are printed in table but between tags `<tr>` and `<td>`. This text is displayed before table. For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  b
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

will looke like

b

a

c

Answer (score 3):

The strings `abc` and `def` are rendered on the top of your page because they are not in your table. Put them into some cell `<td>` and it will solve your problem - text will be in the table.